# Kill only one console app, when multiple are started

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Given the projects like:

[image]

both projects (.Net Core 2.0) are run at startup:

[image]

I am trying to kill only KillingTest app without killing project KillingTestOtherApp, but when I am running code below, both console apps are closed.

**KillingTest**
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KillingTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var processId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
            var process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
```

**KillingTestOtherApp**
Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KillingTestOtherApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**[EDIT]**

I opened the issue on .Netcore github:

[github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1005](http://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1005)

it is known bug in debugging process in Visual Studio when using .NET Core,

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/88707/debugging-multiple-dotnet-core-applications-all-te.html

at present without solution (assuming we want to be able to debug all apps).

Comment: I have just reproduce this based on your post and I got no "problem", the intented app closes, the other stays open. So maybe the problem comes from something that is not in your post.

Comment: @TTT I forgot to say that issue occurs in .Net Core 2.0. However you are right - in .NET 4.6 projects this problem do not occur. I am updating my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the fact you are letting Visual Studio debug both programs. Because of this, when the first app commits Seppuku, Visual Studio is terminating the second program. When I told the second to 'Start without debugging', it continued to run after the first had been terminated.

[image: Start settings]

Comment: Thanks for solution! Out of curiosity, why (in project made in .NET 4.6) i do not have such issue - both projects could be set to start and only one app is closed?

Comment: I remade the two apps in .Net 4.6 as you said and the second kept running. This is strange to me as well. May be an issue with how Visual Studio manages the different frameworks when debugging. Possibly worth asking Microsoft dev team about.

Comment: I opened the issue on .netcore github: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1005 it is known bug in debugging process in visual studio when using.net core, https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/88707/debugging-multiple-dotnet-core-applications-all-te.html I am updating my post.